# How can I check if OnResize event is created on TTabSheet control?

Tags: delphi

I have multiple `TTabSheet` on `TPageControl` and on certain action, user click on a button,  I would like run `OnResize` event on a selected `TTabSheet`. The problem is that not all `TTabSheet` controls have `OnResize` event created.

I have this code on button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTabSheet(PageControl1.ActivePage).OnResize(PageControl1.ActivePage);
end;

procedure TForm1.TabSheet1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // actions on Resize
end;
```

It works when `TabSheet1` is active. But when `TabSheet2` is active and it doesn't have `OnResize` event I get error:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
>   'access vialotion at 0x00000000: read of address 0x00000000'.

I tried to check for nil, like this:

```
If TTabSheet(PageControl1.ActivePage).OnResize(PageControl1.ActivePage) <> nil then...
```

But it doesn't compile:

> E2008 Incompatible type.

The workaround I discovered is for each `TTabSheet` control to have empty `OnResize` event, with just a comment, no code.

Is there any better check than <> nil, that doesn't work,  if `TTabSheet` has `OnResize` event?

Thank you

Comment: If Assigned(PageControl1.ActivePage.OnResize) then ....

Comment: I'd try to avoid calling an event handler from code if I were you.

Comment: OnResize changes how some of the TLabrl and TEdit controls appear. I need it to be executed on button click, too. How can I avoid calling it but to be executed?

Comment: The framework calls events. If you want to do something in response to a button click, and a resize event I would do the following: 1. Create a private method that does that thing. 2. Call that private method from the button click handler. 3. Call that private method from the resize event.

Comment: It's not at all clear what problem you are trying to solve.  Have you created Tabsheet2 in the IDE Form Designer, or are you creating it in code?

Comment: All created in IDE, and on TabSheet1 and other TTabSheet controls I set OnResize events, but nothing for TabSheet2. So TabSheet2 has OnResize in Object  Inspector but not in code in unit1.

Comment: Why the negative score? I made sure I described the problem in details, MVCE is included, error message included. It took me months to ask my first question and was sure I'm not the same as those questionsbwithout all the info. How can I improve it?

Comment: "Why the negative score?" Maybe because your q is **not** an MCVE, it does not contain sufficient information to reproduce your set-up without guesswork.  For instance, I had to ask you how TabSheet2 is created, because that is not stated in your q.

Comment: I see. I was hoping 2 answers with positive score would at least let me stay at 0.

Comment: "I was hoping 2 answers with positive score would at least let me stay at 0."  No, because the votes for the answers are entirely independent of the + or - votes for the question.  It is quite possible for a below-average/poor q to have downvotes of its own but still have upvoted answers.  That's the way SO works. One way to avoid getting a downvoted q is to anticipate (and answer in advance) the questions readers will ask if they want to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok. I just re-read the rules and the question will not get deleted if it has answers. So, all good for first question. Will try better next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  If Assigned(PageControl‌​1.ActivePage.OnResize‌​) 
    then PageControl‌​1.ActivePage.OnResize‌​(Sender);       
end;
```

Comment: Assigned checks for nil, empty and non-attached? Will this work in all or just certain cases?

Comment: @Matej Can you define "empty" and "non-attached"? What are these things? The answer is that there are no such things. If the event handler is `nil` then `Assigned()` returns `False` and no event handler has been attached. It still makes me a bit sick to see code calling an event handler from the outside.

Comment: Ok, thank you David. I am confused by TTabSheet events in Objetct Inspector. It shows they are there but no code has been attached. So they exist but are not assigned. Still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: So if I use Assigned I don't need TTabSheet() before PageControl1.ActivePage?

Comment: @Matejmtj It makes no difference whether it's assigned or not. `ActivePage` is already a `TTabSheet` so there's never a need to explicitly cast it as so.

Comment: OK. I was sure I need to cast everytime I don't reffer to the control by the name.

Comment: @Matejmtj You only need to cast something if its class type differs. For example, it you were provided a `TObject` but you knew that was actually a `TTabSheet`.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now, only when class is noy exacly as control's class.

Comment: @Matejmtj: here is some interesting reading for you: [Assigned or not Assigned, that is the question...](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/assigned-or-not-assigned-that-is-the-question-28836)

Comment: Thank you Remy, right now the link is not working for me but I will read later when it gets fixed - it's Embarcadero's site, expected unreliable website.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably going about this the wrong way. You should not invoke event handlers in your code. Leave that to the framework. Instead write it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoTabsheet1Resize;
begin
  // actions on Resize
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoTabsheet1Resize;
end;

procedure TForm1.TabSheet1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoTabsheet1Resize;
end;
```

Here `DoTabsheet1Resize` is a private method that you define.

Comment: So I need to write this new private method for TabSheet1 and for each of other TabSheets? They are private of what? I know every class can have private methods, so in which class would these be? TTabSheet is defined in Vcl.ComCtrls class TWinControl. There? Or each TButton that executes them?

Comment: Aha I see... its in TForm1! Never created private method so I was confused.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by this comment of yours

> I set OnResize events, but nothing for TabSheet2. So TabSheet2 has OnResize in Object Inspector but not in code in unit1.

I think you may be confused about exactly what goes on the Form Designer, it terms of defining event-handling code.

Try this:

1. On a newly-created blank form, drop a TPageControl, PageControl1, right-click it and create two TabSheets in it, TabSheet1 and TabSheet2.
2. In the OI, click TabSheet1,  click its Events tab in the OI and click the drop-down button in the OnResize event property.  You will find the drop down list empty.
3. Now double-click in Tabsheet1's OnResize event.  Doing this causes the OI to create an empty event handling procedure TabSheet1Resize in the form's code.  It also **assigns** the OnResize **property** of TabSheet1 to this procedure, TabSheet1Resize.  Don't save the form at this point, or the IDE will detect that this procedure contains no code (or comments) and will delete it.
4. In TabSheet1Resize add this code

   `Caption := 'TabSheet1.Resize';`

and save the form's unit.

5. Now select TabSheet2's event tab in the OI and **single**-click in its OnResize event.  At this point TabSheet2's OnResize property is not assigned to any procedure so attempting to call `TabSheet2.OnResize()` will result in an AV, because the value of its OnResize **property** is Nil.
6. Now, In TabSheet2's OnResize, click the drop-down button and you will see
   `TabSheet1Resize` as the single entry in the list.  Select it from the list and now the value of TabSheet2's OnResize property is the same as TabSheet1'1, i.e. the procedure TabSheet1Resize.

Steps 3 and 6 are the ones which are vital for TabSheet1 and TabSheet2 to have the same OnResize event-handler code.

In other words, your comment seems to overlook the difference between the event-handler property (e.g. OnResize) which the object, in this case a TTabSheet **always** has (which is why the OI shows you the event-handler **property**) and the code in the event-handler **procedure**, if any, to which the event-handler property is assigned.

Sorry if all the above is painfully obvious, if it is then I've misunderstood several of your comments.

If you want all the other tabsheets to have the same OnResize handler as TabSheet1, you can set this up in, e.g., your FormCreate event handler, like so:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to PageControl1.PageCount - 1 do
    PageControl1.Pages[i].OnResize := PageControl1.Pages[0].OnResize;
  //  PageControl1.Pages[0] will be equal to TabSheet1, if that's the first Tabsheet
  //   you created
end;
```

Comment: Great explanation! You did missunderstand my question but you recognized correctly my lack of vocabulary: event handler property and event handler procedure. Now I know more.